# Understanind set-notation

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Let $g_1(x)$, $g_2(x)$, $\dots$, $g_k(x)$ are k-functions defined on $\mathbb{R}$. Let $A_1, A_2,\dots,A_k$ subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ such that $g_i(x)$ is monotonic on $A_i$.

**Question:** what does the following statement mean?

> The set $Y$ is the same for each $i = 1,2,\dots,k$; where,
> $$
> Y = \{y: y = g_i(x)\,\, \exists x\in A_i\}
> $$

**My understanding**: the statement is saying that $g_1(A_1) = g_2(A_2) = \dots = g_k(A_k)$, where $g_i(A_i)$ is the image of $A_i$ under $g_i(x)$.

Comment: That seems to be the case,  yes,  though it doesn't make sense with only the assumptions given that that would have to be the case.

Comment: @Alan what other interpretations are possible?